# Issue with try catch

Tags: java, exception

I am throwing an exception from a controller, like below

```
try {
    if (formValidationResult.size() > 0) {
        validationResults.put(errorMsg, formValidationResult);
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    LOGGER.error("Error while performing validation in FormController -->"
                    + exception.getMessage());
    throw new ServiceException(exception.getMessage());
}
if (validationResults.size() > 0) {
    throw new ValidationFailureException(validationResults,"Validation Error");
}
```

Here i am getting a validation error;

> com.ge.dbt.common.exception.ValidationFailureException: Validation
>   Error

Can I include a catch block to catch the `ValidationFailureException` here?

Comment: You are getting the exception that is thrown in the code you show when the size of the result is `>0`. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Why do you want to catch an exception you just threw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that validationResult and formValidationResult are collections, I don't see why there is a need to enclose the call to the size and put methods in a try catch block? What exception are you expecting anyway while checking the size of these collections or inserting a new value anyway?

I can't give you the code because I am typing from my phone but this is what you can do :

1. Indicate that the method containing your code throws a ValidationFailureException in the method signature.
2. Remove the try catch block you have presented  and remove the if block that checks whether validationResult is non empty and the code inside the if block.
3. If formValidationResult is not empty, store the error message in validationResult and throw a ValidationFailureException.

That's it. Clean and simple. No need for any try-catch blocks and no need to separately check if validationResult is not empty before throwing a ValidationFailureException.

Answer (score 5):

Yes Java Allows it.You can throw and handle exception using try catch blocks

```
   try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Here you are throwing and handing exception in the same block. **I don't know why anyone would like to do that.**

**A better way could be** have your method define as `throws ValidationFailureException` and handle that exception from the function which is invoking this code.